# what is happening in a simple test code

Tags: c#

I have the following lines of code, and have looked up the methods and object definitions in Microsoft documentation, but I still do not understand how it works.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace HelloWorld.Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class WhenProgramRuns
    {
        private string _consoleOutput;
        [TestInitialize]
        public void Initialize()
        {
            var w = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            Console.SetOut(w);
            Program.Main(new string[0]);
            _consoleOutput = w.GetStringBuilder().ToString().Trim();
        }
        [TestMethod]
        public void SayHelloWorld()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual("Hello, World", _consoleOutput);
        }
    }
}
```

I do not understand how "w" will capture the result of the execution of Main and why the author of code passed a string [0] when he called Main.

Here is Main:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to spend some time studying how the entrance point to console apps work, how the `out` keyword works` and how argument-passing works.

Comment: Voting to close as "too broad", sure it's a short and simple program, but StackOverflow is not a private coaching / education service.

Comment: @DavidL The `out` keyword isn't used here.

Comment: @Servy yep, you're absolutely right, thanks.  Realized that in hindsight after the edit timer expired.  I think the other two points still stand however.

Comment: @DavidL Indeed they do.

Comment: I happen to know about out and ref. Thank you so much for the info and tolerating my lack of knowledge. Greatly appreciate the answers. If at all possible share some relevant online content on what I need to read to understand the code better. The answers did help immensely however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let's split it to pieces:

> I do not understand how "w" will capture the result of the execution
>   of Main

Technically, it is *incorrect* to say that it'll capture the result of execution. Our `w` is an instance of `StringWriter`.
`StringWriter` implements a `TextWriter` for writing information to a string.

Console will use this `w` instance to write output data.

> and why the author of code passed a string [0] when he called Main

Method main accepts `string[]` as parameter, so in order to invoke it we have to pass something and as we do not really need this arguments later, so to pass an empty array would be ok.

The logic of execution can be described as :

1. Create `StringWriter`.
2. Set console to use this `StringWriter` to output data
3. Run the only overload of Main method with required parameter of `string[]`
4. Get builder by calling `GetStringBuilder()` on `StringWriter` and make it build the resulting string by invoking `ToString()`

Comment: this is a valid answer to an in-valid question. the person asking probably does not know the difference between a Stream, Method Parameter, and an organic watermelon. the question is to broad to be answered here.

Answer (score 0):

The Console.SetOut function redirects standard output from the console to "w".